# Cannot install python package properly in a new ubuntu laptop

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I moved from Windows to Linux and I try to set up all my libraries in Python as I had in Windows. Since, I am new on Linux, I don't know a lot.

I follow this procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

To install the `pip`

```
sudo pip3 install bottle
```

To install the Bottle library. The output message didn't has any error. It said that the install completed. Then I tried to run a python file I have which import this library, but I have the error

> ImportError: No module named bottle

I tried also to run Python from terminal and check to import the package there, but I have the same error.

Edit: For Python version

```
readlink -f $(which python) | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.6
```

Comment: are you running a python 3 or python 2 shell?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Python 2.7.6 Since it was preinstalled in Linux, I forgot to mention the version :)

Comment: what does `which python3` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `/usr/bin/python3` This is the output

Comment: OK try my answer, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed a package for `python3` but are using it in a `python2` shell,  `python` by default refers to  `python2`  on  `ubuntu 14.04` . You need to use  `python3` when referring to the `python3` interpreter and  to start a  `python3`  shell

Comment: Since I am used to work on Python 2.7 and all my projects are written in that, is there any way to install the packages for Python2 instead of installing Python3?

Comment: yes, just use `pip install ...`, if you don't have it installed for python2 download get-pip from here https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run `python get-pip.py`